# TeamCity doesn't generate apk when building an Idea Android project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, teamcity

**What I have:** An IntelliJ Idea Android project stored on a Git server; TeamCity is configured to have an "IntelliJ Idea project" as a Runner type. The project itself is stored on Git with all project-related iml's and xml's: you can just download it, open and press "run", the project gets compiled, an .apk gets placed in the out/production folder.

**What I want:** TeamCity to generate an .apk in addition to .class files and place it in the out/production folder

**The question:** how do I achieve that? Is there a specific setting telling TeamCity that this is an Android project, apart from Idea's project configs?

P.S. Android SDK, dependencies, JDK are all configured correctly, as the project gets compiled successfully. The only issue is that the .apk doesn't get generated.

Comment: Is it `Gradle` project? Or `Ant`?

Comment: I have no idea. Whatever it is (build.xml or build.gradle), it gets generated from idea's project config files, I guess. I got the issue resolved, though.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone faces the same problem:
You have to explicitly declare an artifact (Project Settings -> Artifacts) of an "Android Application" type, and then list its name in TeamCity's Build Step Config.

Comment: Alex, can you provide more detailed answer (screenshots would be too much to ask? ;)). Where do you exactly declare Artifacts? And what exactly do you put in TeamCity's Build Step Config? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6):

To output all "Android Application" (apk) files you can specify +:**/*.apk in the Artifact paths under General Settings for a Build Configuration:

[image]